# JAVA - how to open a browser tab from eclipse?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

I've just got back into Eclipse after 2 years. I have finally forgiven it after I last used it for a mobile development class in 2015 (that was put together as well as a duct-taped carnival ride).

I have taken several for-credit coding classes before, and over the summer, I'm going to take several programming classes via Udemy.

The problem is, I've never built a worthwhile desktop app before via *actual* coding (because I don't think Multimedia Fusion 2 counts). Even worse, I rarely ever use Java.

So now, with blind and eager ambition, I'm looking to develop a desktop app for myself (and for others if it's of any use) that will allow users to create entries where they can enter urls and titles (merely for aesthetic purposes, no effect on the browser), and when some condition is met, the desktop application will open Chrome tabs with tabs to those exact urls.

From this, I'm hoping to understand Java better, like I understand C++. It would be really nice if I could just do it for *any* browser on the first try, but if I had to do each browser separately, I would like to try Chrome firstly, as it's what I use.

If all goes well, I could attempt to make the same app for Chrome as a Chrome App, but for now... :)

---

Here's the core idea/plan:

- Declare a vector of a class called "tabs", where this class contains 2 strings: one for the title, the other for the url. Both should be editable by the user, but for simplicity's sake, we'll just make them an "enter these fields once and now don't edit them" kind of thing to start with.
- When the user wants to add a url to open in Chrome, we add to (or "push back", whatever it's called) the tabs vector with whatever data the user enters.
- When a user presses some key or button, then Chrome will open with those tabs.

---

Here are my ideas on how I could approach this:

- I might be able to download *some kind* of official Chrome development tools into Eclipse that would allow me to manipulate the browser functions, such as opening and closing tabs. If I can pass arguments into those functions, I could iterate through my tabs vector and open them until the end. I've looked for tools like these, and though I may have come across the right one(s) already, nothing really struck me as the "I am your solution!" package deal. I almost imported an official package into Eclipse that looked super-promising, but the official link was dead. :(
- I might be able to use Javascript somehow, because if I understand correctly, I could create a Window object, iterate through the tabs vector, and just call the window.open() function and pass in the url at [i] to the function. But then, would this work for a desktop app?? I've read that NW.js can use Javascript/CSS/hmtl for desktop apps, so I think it could do this, but I've also heard it's a little buggy on Windows 10.
- I'm also looking into Electron, while still on the idea of desktop JavaScript. It looks pretty reliable, actually.

---

But beyond all those ideas, I don't absolutely know what tools I need to use or which ones I could even feasibly use to do this. :/ The options are a little overwhelming, and I'm not sure which ones are worth looking into to do what I want, given the idea I've shared (I'll worry about the rest of the program when the time comes). This really doesn't seem like a hard project, and I really want to get my feet wet into app development, but sometimes I feel a little lost on where to go.

I don't really know what exactly to ask, besides: "Even if it means downloading something else entirely, what IDE/dev kit/whatever could get me started in the right direction and do this task?

Hope this isn't too vague a question, cheers,

-Jon

Comment: Facepalm facepalm - annoyiing us with so much personal story which clouds and blurs out what your questionn is all about.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 simple ways to do this..

The first: In the file menu, navigate as follows... Window -> Show View -> other -> General -> Internal Web Browser

The second: Right click your project in Project Explorer -> Run As -> Run on Server (assuming you have your server properly set up, etc...)

Comment: I was able to get the first one, but not the second. I think I have an idea why I'm doing this, but I'm still not sure about how I will open Chrome tabs from a desktop app. I think I will take a chance and look into Electron and see if I can get started there.

Comment: This launched the system's default browser (Edge in my case)  Would like to be able to use Firefox if possible.  Is there a hidden option to specify?

Comment: Found it.  Additional settings under `Preferences > General > Web Browser`